# Get large data from database in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, file, memory

I have ms sql server and table by name 'files'. Table column type 'image' (or blob) there saved pdf files. And I try select in PHP. My code like

```
        $sql = "SELECT DATALENGTH(file) as len, file FROM files WHERE id = 1";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

       while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $fileLength = $row['len'];
            $file = $row['file'];
            break;
        } 


       echo $fileLength;
       echo strlen($file);
```

In display showed 1448484 and 64512. Variable $file taked just 64512.
File memory in database 1.4 MB. In php code variable $file taked just 64KB. In fact variable size of $file must 1.4 MB. Why? How change this limit? Help me please. Sorry for my English

Comment: are you expecting just one value? or multiple? whats up with that `break;` and `file_kg` isn't declared in your columns selected, only `file`

Comment: Im executing one value, but there not problem

Comment: Yes, there no file_kg, just file. I changed

Comment: change cloumn from `blob` to `longblob`. but with current scenario i am unable to understand your problem

Comment: File memory in database 1.4 MB. In php code variable $file taked just 64KB. In fact variable size of $file must 1.4 MB.

Comment: "SELECT len = DATALENGTH(file), `file` FROM files  WHERE id = 1";